# How to access ProgressBar in ListView in C# WPF without Name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm working on a project in C# with WPF. I have a `ListView` that is populated by binds to an object, which _name is a field of. I want to be able to update a specific `ProgressBar` by knowing which _name I want to update.  So if the current _name is "Task A", I want to update the `ProgressBar` in the same row as "Task A". However, since I can't name the progress bars (I got an error message when trying to bind data to the Name), I haven't been able to figure out how to access the `ProgressBar` from the code. I've tried using Tags, but I haven't been able to figure out how to access a control with a certain tag.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Shown below is some of the XAML of my project.

```
 <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="30">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding _name}" IsChecked="True"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding _name}">Task Name</GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ProgressBar Width="145" Height="15" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding _progress}" Tag="{Binding _name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't access the `ProgessBar` element. Instead you bind its `Value` property to a property of the source object that you update.

`_progress` and `_name` (you should rename these by the way) should be public *properties* of your data type, i.e. the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` that you use as the `ItemsSource` for the `ListView`.

This class should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
public class DataObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _progress;
    public double Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set { _progress = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Progress"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ProgressBar Width="145" Height="15" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}" Tag="{Binding _name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

You then simply change the `Progress` property of the specific item in the `ItemsSource` collection of the `ListView`, .e.g.:

```
var col = listView.ItemsSource as List<DataObject>;
var item = col.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "some name...");
if(item != null)
    item.Value = 100.0;
```

Comment: I followed what you said and made my dataobject class implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and added the event and function you showed, however the progress bar doesn't update visually. If I debug print when I update the progress it outputs the right numbers, so the field is updating correctly.

Comment: Did you really bind to the *property* in your XAML, and not to the backing field?

Comment: I forgot to update the code that updates the property to use Progress instead of _progress.  Thank you!